# How to calculate difference between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I want to calculate difference between two dates (using SQL Request) with this format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",the result should be in hours/minutes.

```
example: "2011-08-02 18:00:00" - "2011-08-03 09:01:00" = 15h and 1 min
```

1/I haven't found a function that calculate what I want ,just found TIMEDIFF() and DATEDIFF()

2/Also my request don't work because the subquery return more than one row ,I have tried to calculate with datediff to only test the request

```
select sum(DATEDIFF((select changegroup.CREATED
from changegroup,changeitem
where changegroup.id=changeitem.groupid
and oldString='Closed'
and changegroup.issueid=10301),
(select changegroup.CREATED
where changegroup.id=changeitem.groupid
and newString='Closed'
and changegroup.issueid=10301))) as somme
from changegroup,changeitem;
```

How can I calculate the difference between two dates and how can I fix my sql request?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. the following returns "15h and 01 min" which I think is the format you wanted

```
SELECT Time_format(Timediff('2011-08-03 09:01:00', '2011-08-02 18:00:00'),
              '%Hh and %i min')
```

2. hard to answer without knowing more about the two tables you're querying. Could you expand your question a little?

Comment: Thank you very much for the TIME_FORMAT()   ,I will update my post to add more details